# How to eliminate screen flicker when getting handle of screen object to DrawFocusRect

Tags: delphi

I am attempting to draw a focused rectangle around a selected screen object in my Apprehend Screen Capture Component that was developed many years ago.  I can DrawFocusRect by getting the handle to the object under the cursor with Handles := WindowFromPoint( P ); but that requres me to hide then show self for it to work otherwise the handle to self is returned.

Unfortunately when I hide and show the form it causes flicker when the form is hidden and shown.

I can get the bitmap of the selected object with no problem, just painting the selected object is driving me nuts.

Does anyone have any suggestions to draw a FocusedRect around the selected object so there is no flickering?  Is there any API to get a handle to the screen if a form lies on top of it?

I tried using Handles := WindowFromDC(ScreenDC) so I do not have to hide and show the form, but WindowFromDC still returns the form rather than the screen.

The TCaptureObjectForm is transparent and lies over the screen.  I need the TCaptureObjectForm in the component.

// FormMouseMove event - added 08/2/2011

```
procedure TCaptureObjectForm.FormMouseMove( Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer );
const
  crHand = -18;
var
  P: TPoint;
  Handles: HWND;
  Rect: TRect;
  ScreenDC: HDC;
begin
  // hide the TCaptureObjectForm form so the screen is found by WindowFromPoint
  Self.Hide;
  // get the object on the screen
  GetCursorPos( P );
  Handles := WindowFromPoint( P );
  // tried this but it returns self.handle rather than the screen handle
  //ScreenDC := GetDC( 0 );
  //Handles := WindowFromDC(ScreenDC);
  //ReleaseDC( 0, ScreenDC );
  // restore the TCaptureObjectForm
  Self.Show;
  // get object rect
  GetWindowRect( Handles, Rect );
  // draw a rect to show it is focused
  Self.Canvas.DrawFocusRect( Rect );
end;
```

Comment: After I set DoubleBuffered to true the flicker was alot less but the FocusedRect still flickers of course.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Sorry don't have another idea...

Comment: Maybe David Heffernan's answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6946371/859646) question can help you.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143045) is an example in Visual Basic from Microsoft doing something very similar to what you need.

They take the following approach:

1. Capture the mouse in `Form_MouseDown`.
2. As the mouse moves, draw a rectangle around the window pointed with the mouse: `Form_MouseMove`.
3. Release the mouse in `Form_MouseUp` and also invalidate the entire screen to erase the last rectangle drawn.

They draw directly in the window that they are selecting. I don't think that all flickering can be avoided using the transparent window approach.

That code sample seems incomplete and doesn't work well, so I've modified it (and translated to Delphi):

```
// Not global variables, but private form ones
var
  HwndLastTracked: HWND;
  CapturedMouse: boolean;

procedure InvertTracker(hwndWindow: HWND);
var
  rc: TRect;
  dc: HDC;
  pen, oldPen: HPEN;
  oldBrush: HBRUSH;
  style, exStyle: longint;
  cx, cy: integer;
begin
  GetWindowRect(hwndWindow, rc);

  // Window coordinates of the origin (top-left corner) of a window is (0, 0)
  OffsetRect(rc, -rc.Left, -rc.Top);

  // DC returned by GetWindowDC covers the full window area, but in Windows
  // Vista/7 it seems to be clipped excluding the nonclient region, due to
  // DWM handling nonclient drawing, so it doesn't allow painting over it.
  // Thus we need to skip this nonclient area and that is why I adjust the
  // window rect to match the client area. Using GetClientRect instead of
  // GetWindowRect is not suitable as excludes scroll bars and child 
  // parts drawed in WM_NCPAINT, such as Windows' WS_EXEDGEs and Delphi's
  // bevels.

  style := GetWindowLong(hwndWindow, GWL_STYLE);
  exStyle := GetWindowLong(hwndWindow, GWL_EXSTYLE);

  if style and WS_CAPTION <> 0 then begin
    if exStyle and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW <> 0 then
      cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMCAPTION)
    else
      cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION);

    // discard area covered by caption 
    Inc(rc.Top, cy);
  end;

  if style and WS_THICKFRAME <> 0 then begin
    cx := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME);
    cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME);
  end
  else if style and WS_DLGFRAME <> 0 then begin
    cx := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDLGFRAME);
    cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDLGFRAME);
  end
  else if style and WS_BORDER <> 0 then begin
    cx := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER);
    cy := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER);
  end
  else begin
    cx := 0;
    cy := 0;
  end;

  if (cx <> 0) or (cy <> 0) then begin
    // discard area covered by borders
    OffsetRect(rc, cx, cy);
    Dec(rc.Right, cx*2);
    Dec(rc.Bottom, cy*2);
  end;

  // Windows API functions don't raise exceptions, so I don't use try-finally

  dc := GetWindowDC(hwndWindow);

  // Option 1: focused rect
  //DrawFocusRect(dc, rc);

  // Option 2: inverted thick border
  SetROP2(dc, R2_NOT);
  pen := CreatePen(PS_INSIDEFRAME, 3 * GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER), 0);
  oldPen := SelectObject(dc, pen);
  oldBrush := SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));

  Rectangle(dc, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Right, rc.Bottom);

  SelectObject(dc, oldBrush);
  SelectObject(dc, oldPen);
  DeleteObject(pen);
  // End option 2

  ReleaseDC(hwndWindow, dc);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if SetCapture(Handle) <> 0 then begin
    CapturedMouse := true;
    HwndLastTracked := 0;
    Screen.Cursor := crCross;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  hwndCaptured: HWND;
begin
  if CapturedMouse then begin
    hwndCaptured := WindowFromPoint(ClientToScreen(Point(X, Y)));

    // Uncomment this for track root windows instead of childs
    //hwndCaptured := GetAncestor(hwndCaptured, GA_ROOT);

    if hwndCaptured <> HwndLastTracked then begin
      if HwndLastTracked <> 0 then
        InvertTracker(HwndLastTracked);
      InvertTracker(hwndCaptured);
      HwndLastTracked := hwndCaptured;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if CapturedMouse then begin
    ReleaseCapture;
    CapturedMouse := false;

    if HwndLastTracked <> 0 then begin
      InvertTracker(HwndLastTracked);
      HwndLastTracked := 0;
    end;

    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a screenshot of how Microsoft uses this technique in Visual Studio's Spy++. The red balloon and text are mine!

[image: Spy++]

Comment: I attempted to convert the Visual Basic code to Delphi, but the whole screen turns black and the entire screen was focused... gone back to my old code for now...

Comment: @Bill: I've edited my answer and added a working example made from Microsoft's buggy code.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about skipping GetWindowDC. A DC retrieved by it certainly allows drawing on the entire window.

Comment: JRL-  The code compiles in my component but the whole window turns opaque black and the only thing visible on the screen is the taskbar in win 7.  I can still select the object even though I can not see it... the window must remain transparent for this to work.  The selection is not visible either.

Comment: @Bill: With this technique you don't have a transparent window, only a small "find window" like that of the screenshot, and the user has to click on the "finder tool", drag it over the window he/she wishes to select, and release the mouse button. I've tested it in XP and Win 7.

Comment: @Sertac: This comment was a little ambiguous, so I've corrected it. I refer to skipping painting over the nonclient area, no to skip GetWindowDC. DC returned by GetWindowDC covers the full window area, but seems to be clipped excluding the nonclient region.

Comment: @JRL - You are wrong, there's no clipping. It's just that you're calculating the rectangle wrong. Remove all code beginning (including) with the first `ScreenToClient(..` call up to the (excluding) `dc := GetWindowDC(..` call. Just replace all that fiddling with `OffsetRect(rc, -rc.Left, -rc.Top);`.

Comment: @JRL - I've done the modification for you. It's more concise and correct now, hence +1 ;)

Comment: @Sertac: This is a more elegant way, and was the first I try, but it doesn't show the inverted rectangle for top level windows in Windows 7 (and probably Vista), due to DWM handling non-client drawing. I think my code patching the rectangle is necessary and provides a similar experience to the user independently of OS version. Besides that, making it dependent of DWM presence will cause two different appearances when selecting top-level windows: 1) a rectangle around non-client area (w/o DWM); 2) a rectangle around client area (w DWM).

Comment: @JRL - You code was incorrectly using `ScreenToClient` which gives **client coordinates**, and then was struggling to convert these client coordinates to window coordinates. I thought I was correcting this error. Please rollback your answer..

Comment: @Sertac: You are right, using ScreenToClient was nonsense. I've reverted to my previous code but using your OffsetRect instead of the two ScreenToClient calls. I've also cleaned-up a bit the code patching the rectangle and included the reference to the DWM issues in the code comment.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.DoubleBuffered:=True;
end;
```

Comment: this has the downside that it stops some components rendering properly

Comment: Didn't had that problem and i am using it all the time...That's why borland implemented it to reduce flicker but i don't know a better solution.If you have one please tell me because it's a problem witch i often encounter.

Comment: A couple of examples, both Vista up: 1. Try a drop down list in Windows Basic theme. Looks terrible with double buffering of the form. 2. A default or focused `TButton` pulses to indicate that it will be pressed if you hit the enter key. But not if you have form double buffering. In fact not if the button is double buffered. I have managed to remove all flicker from my app without recourse to double buffering. One of these days I'll write down how I did it in a SO wiki question.