# Get window handle underneath mouse pointer, while ignoring a semi-transparent window

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, transparency

I've created a semi-transparent form (60% opacity with black background color) that my app launches, maximized, over the entire screen. Basically, it casts a gray color on the entire desktop.

When the user mouses-over a window on the desktop, I want to get that window's handle (hWnd).

The easy way to do this, which is working for me, is:

1. Temporarily hide my form (OR, temporarily set my form's opacity to 0.0)
2. Call [GetCursorPos][1]
3. Call [WindowFromPoint][2]
4. Show my form again

**The problem with this approach is that my form / the screen blinks, which I don't like.**

I've tried to fix this in two ways:

- I figure there should be a way to get the hWnd of the window directly underneath my form by calling [ChildWindowFromPointEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632677%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (passing-in the hWnd of the desktop and `CWP_SKIPTRANSPARENT`), but it doesn't seem to work. I also played with [ChildWindowFromPoint][4] and [RealChildWindowFromPoint][5] with no success. (P.S. Raymond Chen discusses the differences between these calls, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/30/10110077.aspx) and it seems to me that ChildWindowFromPointEx is designed to do exactly what I need)
- I tried preventing the entire desktop from refreshing (kind of "freezing" the screen momentarily) by using (1) `SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0)` before I hide my form and (2) `SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow(), WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0)` after I hide my form. This didn't work quite right: some areas of the screen would freeze, some weird black blocks would appear, etc.  I do know, however, that (1) does work, because one time I called (1) and didn't call (2) and my desktop appeared completely frozen (had to reboot, even TaskMgr didn't render correctly).  I also tried using SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout on my form, but I don't think they are meant to handle my case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Had to remove a bunch of useful links because I'm a new user.  That's kind of lame.

Comment: Are you looking for top level windows, or do need the child window? And how do you want to handle any translucent windows you come across?

Comment: @David-Heffernan YES, only looking for top-level windows (immediate children of Desktop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the checking yourself since your need to customise beyond that what the standard functions offer.

1. Call `EnumWindows()` to get a list of top-level windows.
2. Remove your semi-transparent window from this list.
3. For each window in the list use `PtInRegion()` to determine whether or not the mouse is over the window. Remove any windows that don't fit the bill.
4. Use `GetNextWindow()`, starting from one of the remaining windows to walk the z-order and find out which of the candidates is at the top.

Comment: Not exactly sure but EnumWindows might even enumerate respecting the z-order rendering (4) unnecessary.

Comment: If it's not documented then you can't rely on that behaviour

Comment: @sertac I did indeed look at that but there's no doc. I bet you're right though.

Comment: I think another way to get a list of all of top level windows is Process.GetProcesses().  And examine the .MainWindowTitle (if it's not null or blank, I think it means its a top-level window) and .MainWindowHandle