# How to recover the semi-transparent Window where the mouse click through?

Tags: c#, winapi, transparency

I want to recover the Window that I set the semi-transparent to 50% where the mouse is.

I can't get this Window handle from the mouse pointer for its Click-Through. And if I don't set click trough, it is easy to solve.

The following steps from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946371/get-window-handle-underneath-mouse-pointer-while-ignoring-a-semi-transparent-wi) may be a solution, but it will hide the semi-transparent Window. So is there a better way to get the semi-transparent Window information, and then to show it transparent 100%?

> Temporarily hide my form (OR, temporarily set my form's opacity to 0.0)
> Call [GetCursorPos][1]
> Call [WindowFromPoint][2]
> Show my form again

If there is one Window, I can store the Window handle where the mouse is and then recover it, but I want to set more than 1 Window transparent to 50% and recover them one by one with the mouse pointer.

Recover the mouse with the semi-transparent Window by the stored handle using WinAPI.

```
var WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
var WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
var GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & (~WS_EX_TRANSPARENT));
```

If I store the handle of the Windows that will be set the transparency to 50% in an array, I can't recognize which one handle is match the Window where the mouse pointer.

It is just a Windows Desktop Program to do the function above through Shourcuts. As I said, it is easy except add the mouse Click Trough. The Window may be a normal program like the Explorer, Notepad, and so on, and maybe Winforms, I find it is hard to be used on the normal program, and also it will be good if the function with Click-Trough suits for more than 1 Window like Winforms.

Comment: "If there is one Window, I can store the Window handle where the mouse is and then recover it, but I want to set more than 1 Window transparent to 50% and recover them one by one with the mouse pointer." So make a `List<>` of your handles? Enumerate over them and see if the current mouse position is within one of their bounds...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you for your attention, maybe it is hard to match the value of the `List<>` with the mouse pointer directly? Or should I store the Window rectangle in the screen with the Window Object?

Comment: What kind of Windows are these? WinForms Windows? In that case, you have the `Bounds` Property, so it's just `Bounds.Contains([Point])`, if the Windows don't overlap. Otherwise, you also have to use `GetWindow()` to see which one comes first. Or something along that line. -- You should use `SetWindowLongPtr`, but, if this is actually WinForms stuff, which don't you use its *native* methods to set the transparency? It already calls the appropriate `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`. If `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` is needed, it can be set in `CreateParams`.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain a bit more about your app. Are you creating the semi-transparent windows? Are they external to your app? How are they being selected?

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, I will have a try at the only WinForms.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I add the details at the bottom.